# Почему коллизий не может быть на современных роутерах?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, tcp-ip, пакет, коллизии

В интернете пишут, что при передаче пакетов через единую среду могут возникать коллизии. Но вроде как на современных роутерах такой проблемы нет. А почему непонятно

Comment: Если отбросить wi-fi (в нем коллизии возможны), то сейчас все устройства подключаются к роутеру порт-порт *в полнодуплексном режиме*, поэтому общей среды передачи нет, следовательно нет и коллизий

Comment: Но портов же несколько, а выход один. Например 3 компьютера подключены к одному роутеру

Comment: Каждое устройство подключается к отдельному порту роутера. И с портом связано достаточно памяти для буферизации пакетов.

Comment: Ну а порт WAN (общий для всех) через который пойдут все данные со всех портов? Там-то пересекаются?

Comment: Конечно нет. Это такой же полнодуплексный порт на другом роутере.

Comment: Реально не понимаю. Например компьютеры с портов 1,2 и 3 решили одновременно выйти в интернет - по идее данные с этих трех портов пойдут через общий кабель (который идет от роутера к провайдеру). Или порт 1 и 3 решили одновременно передать скажем видеофайл порту 1. И почему тут не может быть коллизий?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев , роутер - это не муфта, где скручены кабели (так были бы коллизии, как в топологии шина). Ему приходят пакеты с разных портов, складываются, грубо говоря,  в очередь порта. Из очереди извлекаются по одному. Поэтому с одного порта идёт один пакет.